# Asp.net MVC use user control (.ascx) with IIS 7 integrated application pool

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, user-controls, application-pool

I am using user control `(.ascx)` in my `asp.net mvc` application for telerik redspell (spell checker). For that I have added the Handlers and `HttpHandlers` in the `web.config` and load the user control using `@Html.Partial()`. I have to change the application pool from integrated to `.Net 4.5 classic in my local IIS 8` (Before this functionality my application was running on the port with default application pool).

The whole functional flow works fine with the above configuration in my local `IIS 8`. But when I published it on my production server `(IIS 7 + .Net 4.0 classic application pool)`, It is not working as expected.

Is there any way to use user control with integration or default application pool?

Your help will get me a relief!!!